# Troubles with IN in Yii query builder

Tags: mysql, yii, query-builder

I use Yii Framework and i need to build difficult query with many conditions. 
I'm filling 2 arrays $conditions and $values.
And i have one problem.
Below is example
When i use

```
$usersId = '1,2';
$conditions[] = 'e.user_id IN(:usersId)';
$values[':usersId'] = $usersId;
```

I get only value from user_id = 1

When i'm not use option and write manually

```
$usersId = '1,2';
$conditions[] = 'e.user_id IN(' . $usersId . ')';
```

no problem.

Of course i can use second construction, but it seems not very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `addInCondition`

```
$criteria->addInCondition('e.user_id',array(1,2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yii way would be to use [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail) `addInCondition` function

```
$usersId = array(1,2); //must be array
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('user_id',$usersId);

$result = MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 1):

$values[':usersId'] = $usersId;

If I understand your wuestion correctly, you can use the BindParam function in yii?

Instead of this - $values[':usersId'] = $usersId;

Write this - $command->BindParam(':usersId', $usersId, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Very simply, you're binding your parameters to your command statement.

Hope it works!